# I am trying to find a list of file names under a directory and all subdirectories in DOS

Tags: windows

I am trying to get a list of all files under every directory and subdirectory in a windows directory.  I know how to list all of the files and folders along with the file path, but I just need the files names under all subdirectories.  All the files end with an extension ".tif".

Comment: Really DOS? Then why the Windows tag?

Comment: In a program? At the console? A little more info if @Јοеу's answer doesn't do what you want

Answer (score 4):

```
dir /s /b *.tif
```

Sometimes consulting the help really *does* help:

```
> help dir
Displays a list of files and subdirectories in a directory.

DIR [drive:][path][filename] [/A[[:]attributes]] [/B] [/C] [/D] [/L] [/N]
  [/O[[:]sortorder]] [/P] [/Q] [/R] [/S] [/T[[:]timefield]] [/W] [/X] [/4]

...
/B          Uses bare format (no heading information or summary).
...
/S          Displays files in specified directory and all subdirectories.
...
```